# How to assign an instance object to protobuf message attribute

Tags: python, protocol-buffers

With `test.photo` file:

```
syntax = "proto3";

message Phone {
  string number = 1;
}
message User {
  Phone phone = 1;
}
```

compiled with it:

`python -m grpc_tools.protoc -I. --python_out=. test.proto`

running:

```
    import test_pb2
    user = test_pb2.User()
    phone = test_pb2.Phone(number = '(123) 456 7890')
    user.phone = phone
```

raises an `AttributeError` exception:

```
    Assignment not allowed to field "phone" in protocol message object.
```

Is there a way to assign a `phone` object to `user.phone` attribute?

Comment: Does this same issue arise if you instantiate Phone first, and then pass phone to User's constructor?

Comment: The order the objects are declared has no impact.

Comment: I'm asking if an error is thrown if you use `User`'s constructor, instead of assigning directly to it's `phone` attribute:
`user = test_pb2.User(phone=phone)`

Answer (score 0):

As the error states, protobuf messages don't support assignment. There is a built in method `CopyFrom` which overwrites the message with the given message's values/attributes.

The following will populate the attributes of `user.phone` with those of `phone`:

```
import test_pb2

user = test_pb2.User()
phone = test_pb2.Phone(number = '(123) 456 7890')
user.phone.CopyFrom(phone)
```